# xslt pass template match and for-each value at runtime

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to use a single xsl to apply to multiple XML with different root element and select element? Please advise.
original xml-1:

```
<employees>
<employee>
<name>ABC</name>
<id>123</id>
<dept>sales</dept>
<city>XYZ</city>
</employee>
</employees>
```

xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="employees">

        <xsl:element name="doc">
            <xsl:for-each select="employee">

            <xsl:element name="set">
                <xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">Name</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">Id</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                </xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">Department</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="dept"/>
                </xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">City</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>
```

This produces output as:

```
<doc>
<set>
<field name="Name">ABC</field>
<field name="Id">123</field>
<field name="Department">sales</field>
<field name="City">XYZ</field>
</set>
</doc>
```

I want to use the same xsl for transforming the below xml.

```
<customers>
<customer>
<name>DEF</name>
<id>456</id>
<city>DEF</city>
</customer>
</customers>
```

I tried to use variable and set the root element and for-each select element at runtime through java program. But it gives error.

```
<xsl:variable name="rootElement"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="subElement"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="$rootElement">

        <xsl:element name="set">
            <xsl:for-each select="$subElement">
```

Error:

```
FATAL ERROR:  'line 4: Error parsing XPath expression '$rootElement'.'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: line 4: Error parsing XPath expression '$rootElement'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone pls suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You can re-use the same XSLT only if all input documents will have the same hierarchy structure: table/records/fields in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following generalized version with no reference of employees or customers but matches template to the children of the root:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>        

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="doc">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:element name="set">
        <xsl:element name="field">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">Name</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="field">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">Id</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="field">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">Department</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="dept"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="field">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">City</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `union` operator. Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="employees|customers">
        <xsl:element name="doc">
            <xsl:for-each select="employee|customer">
                <set>
                    <field name="Name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </field>
                    <field name="Id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                    </field>
                    <xsl:if test="dept">
                        <field name="Department">
                            <xsl:value-of select="dept"/>
                        </field>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <field name="City">
                        <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
                    </field>
                </set>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```